# Why image src is showing twice localhost and port?

Tags: html

I have image retunred from server?

the path is https:\localhost:7229\Images\sample-clouds-400x300.jpg

When I put it in src it gets in the netwrok as

https:\localhost:7229\https:\localhost:7229\Images\sample-clouds-400x300.jpg

Any Reason ?

Answer (score 1):

This comes from your typo:

```
https:\localhost:7229\Images\sample-clouds-400x300.jpg
      î There should be 2 \
```

Since only one slash is used, the path is seen as a relative path, the browser then transforms it into an absolute path by adding the current page's url.